# Specifying the default aligment used by Eigen for Eigen::Map in order to avoid performance degradation

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, memory-alignment, eigen3

I have a dense vector `VectorXd b` and a sparse matrix `SparseMatrix<double> A` (stored in compressed form). I know that Eigen takes care to correctly align the memory for `b` and `A` in order to use SSE or AVX instructions.
Now I need to use a map for `b` and `A`, that is:

```
Map<VectorXd> b_map;
Map<SparseMatrix<double>> A_map;
```

I would like to get the same performances using `b_map` and `A_map` in place of `b` and `A`, so I think I should specify the right memory alignment.
For vector I could use:

```
Map<VectorXd,AlignedXY> b_map( b.data(), n );
```

but there's no an equivalent choice for sparse matrix. Why?
How can I set the value of `AlignedXY` with the same memory alignment used for `b`?

Comment: I didn't know Eigen could use vector instructions for sparse matrices. Do they make a measurable difference?

Comment: I supposed it uses vectorization both for dense and sparse data. If not, the question remains valid only for dense vectors and matrices.

Comment: But for a dense matrix you already found the alignment parameter of Map...

Comment: No, the problem is to how to set the correct value for AlignedXY so that it is equal to the default value used by VectorXd or MatrixXd.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. The parameter is a promise you make to Eigen that the external buffer you are mapping has this alignment. So you should pass the maximal value that you are certain your external type is aligned on. Or do you want to know what alignment Eigen can take advantage of so you can pass that to aligned_alloc (for instance) when you allocate your own memory? I see...

Comment: I declare `VectorXd b( n )`. I would like to declare `Map<VectorXd,alignment_value> b_map( b.data(), n )` with the correct value for `alignment_value` as used by Eigen in  `b` declaration.

Comment: Maybe is there a macro for default alignment value used by Eigen?

Comment: I found EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES macro definition in Macros.h. Maybe it should be used to set alignment_value...

Comment: I confirm: `Map<VectorXd,EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES> b_map( b.data(), n )` works. With my project properties (VS2013) EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES is 16.